# What is a marker of a stream and why there's only 1 marker in a stream?

Tags: c++, stream

From *C++ Primer 5th* (emphasized mine):

> **There Is Only One Marker**
>
> The fact that the library distinguishes between the “putting” and “getting” versions of the `seek` and `tell` functions can be misleading. Even though the library makes this distinction, **it maintains only a single marker in a stream—there is not a distinct read marker and write marker**.
>
> When we’re dealing with an input-only or output-only stream, the distinction isn’t even apparent. We can use only the `g` or only the `p` versions on such streams. If we attempt to call `tellp` on an `ifstream`, the compiler will complain. Similarly, it will not let us call `seekg` on an `ostringstream`.
>
> The `fstream` and `stringstream` types can read and write the same stream. **In
>   these types there is a single buffer that holds data to be read and written and a single marker denoting the current position in the buffer.** The library maps both the `g` and `p` positions to this single marker.
>   Because there is only a single marker, we must do a seek to reposition the
>   marker whenever we switch between reading and writing.

---

All I know about stream buffer is from this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf. From the text and diagram, I know that a stream is a source containing data, which can at most have **2** buffers, maintained by **6** pointers.

So what is the marker mentioned in quote **practically**? And why is it saying that there's only 1 marker for a stream that allows both input and output, which violates my basic understanding of stream?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, so just an educated guess based on my own knowledge:

1. the so called *marker* is the current **offset** from beginning of the stream, so the first byte is `offset = 0`.
2. the distinction between "putting" and "getting" allows the user to implement his own stream classes that uses different `g` and `p`, thus not relaying on a single marker for reading/writing, this approach provides more flexibility, since you're not tied to a single marker.